# Vim jump to a file using ctr-w gF with a @ in the path like dirwith@funnyname/path:34

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vim, rvm, page-jump

My stack trace errors in ruby on rails look like below. I have happily used ctr-w gF to jump to the file and go to the line number following the file for a while.

However I started using RVM and gem_sets, and this puts a @ symbol in the dir which apparently confuses Vim. How can I use my beloved ctr-w gF while this is the case?

```
/Users/x/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@idance/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/whiny_nil.rb:48:in `method_missing'
/Users/x/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@idance/gems/arel-2.0.10/lib/arel/table.rb:103:in `[]'
/Users/x/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@idance/gems/activerecord-3.0.7/lib/active_record/counter_cache.rb:34:in `reset_counters'
/Users/x/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@idance/gems/activerecord-3.0.7/lib/active_record/counter_cache.rb:19:in `each'
/Users/x/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@idance/gems/activerecord-3.0.7/lib/active_record/counter_cache.rb:19:in `reset_counters'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Include the `@` character in `'isfname'`.

```
:set isf+=@-@
```

For more information:

:h 'isfname'